# Printer not reachable in network

Tags: networking, ping, printer, access-point

i've a low-cost printer Samsung i provided to configure in my network.
i gave it a static IP and connected to my AP. i can ping (and use) the printer only if i'm connected to the same AP. why can't i ping this printer from any other pc in the LAN?
the positive thing is that the printer maintained the static IP and every day it's reachable if i'm connected to the same AP.
this AP, in order to work, is connected to another AP that is, in turn, connected to the main switch of the workshop.

Answer (score 0):

So, you AP (wireless) is actually a bridge/Extender for another AP, which is connected to the main Switch.

Try looking at the AP Settings to see if certain network segregation is set-up, is the primary AP from your Provider ? because some providers configure their Wireless networks to be split from the LAN network (as is the case with my provider in BE).

Could be as simple as that the AP and LAN are 2 segregated networks.

Can you ping a AP Connected computer from a LAN Attached device ?

regards,

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/9BzTcKP.png) this is the same device pinged from LAN and from AP client. i lost the IPaddress of AP after configuring it as AP, i can't find how to re-enter in its configuration page

Comment: yes, i can ping an IP under AP from a LAN client

Answer (score 0):

What are the ping times when you are not connected to the AP? It doesn't make sense that the AP would be segregated if you are able to ping. If you do an -arp a from a Windows machine after pinging the printer, does the MAC address for the IP of the printer match the MAC of the printer?

If you are able to ping from outside of the AP, and the MAC is correct, I would be curious how you have the printer installed. Is it installed on your machine by IP address?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/9LTKGt2.png). everything seems correct from this client

Comment: You will need to use an subnet scanner to find the IP that the AP has so you can check the configuration. By default they are set to DHCP. You can use this one: http://filehippo.com/download_advanced_ip_scanner/

You can then enter the IP in your browser to access the configuration page once you find it on the network. You might try 192.168.0.99 because that looks like what is replying when you try to ping the device. Are you sure the AP isn't a router? What is the make and model?

Comment: is a TP-LINK TL-WA854RE, surely not a router. i thought it only had to extend the range. i never read about "segregation" during configuration.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Quick Setup wizard that would allow for a guest/segregated network. What device is on 192.168.0.99?

Comment: .99 is the PC on LAN i used to ping

Comment: I thought it might be that. Let us know if you are able to find the AP and notice anything off in the configuration.You have internet access when you are connected to the AP, correct?